# When i Click on edit text in vb.net using telerik it disappear the row

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid

[image]

When i click in edit link as below image shows.after it display blank box as shown in image

Answer (score 0):

Generally this behavior is caused when the grid is configured to use Custom Form Template and the template is empty. If the EditFormType is set to Template, there must be a FormTemplate with controls created, or if it set to WebUserControl, then the user controls must be supplied for it. For more information see [Custom Edit Forms](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/custom-edit-forms).

You can also check out the [Grid - Form Template Edit Form](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultcs.aspx) demo for Custom FormTemplate and [Grid - Edit Form Types](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/edit-form-types/defaultcs.aspx) demo to see an example for WebUserControl.